# Trouble getting ng2-datetime imported

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to get ng2-datetime imported into my app because it seems like it's the only datepicker popup available that lets you limit the date range.  Anyway, according to its [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime), I installed `ng2-datetime` through npm.

Then I imported `bootstrap-datepicker` and `bootstrap-timepicker` as listed in the docs.  I also installed jQuery and imported jQuery.  Then I imported the `NKDateTime` component and added it to my module declarations.

All I get is

```
ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:149:26
Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:150:36
Cannot find name '$'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:167:18
Cannot find name '$'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:171:26
Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:172:36
Cannot find name '$'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\rakibler\Projects\efile\node_modules\ng2-datetime\src\ng2-datetime\ng2-datetime.ts:198:18
Cannot find name '$'.
```

I'm using `angular2 RC7` and `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4`

If this is an insurmountable problem, I am open to any other datepicker that lets me restrict the min and max date values.

Comment: Could you please post your webpack.config.js?

Comment: @yurzui no, sorry, it's just the default one that's generated by the CLI I guess.  There is no webpack config actually in my project

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by installing the jquery type definition.

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following command:
`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

More info on: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

1. Update **tsconfig.json** file

   npm install @types/jquery --save-dev

and then add

```
"types": [
//...., your code
"jquery" // <- add this
]
```

2. Need to import some libs:

   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
   import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
   import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css';
   import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';
   import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css';
   import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js';

I'm using angular-seed, so I will config it like this:

```
"project.config.ts"

// Add `NPM` third-party libraries to be injected/bundled.
    this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
      ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
        { src: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', inject: 'libs' },

      // {src: 'lodash/lodash.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
        { src: 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', inject: 'libs' },

        { src: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', inject: true }, // inject into css section
        { src: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', inject: true }, // inject into css section
        { src: 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map', inject: true }, // inject into css section

        { src: 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', inject: 'libs' },
        { src: 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css', inject: true },
        { src: 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css', inject: true },
        { src: 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js', inject: 'libs' },
    ];

// Add packages (e.g. ng2-translate)
let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
    // required for dev build
    //....
    {
        name:'ng2-datetime',
        path:'node_modules/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.js',
        packageMeta:{
            main:"ng2-datetime.js",
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy fix:

- install `"ng2-datetime": "1.2.1"`
- install `"@types/jquery": "^2.0.33"`
- specify `"types": ["jquery"]` within *tsconfig.json*

This fixed all issues for me.