# Angular2 RC7 ng2-datetime Error- ($(...).datepicker is not a function)

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I declare some var and replace $ to jQuery.

1.i declare var jQuery: any;
   2. replace $ to jQuery;  (error clear in ts)
   3. configure in system.config.json and import in app.module
   4. And i have bootstrap-datepicker in node-module

The error is datetime input box didn't work and the error show in console like this ($(...).datepicker is not a function). I changed $ to jQuery in ts.Please Help Me.

ng2-datetime.ts

```
  import {
            Component, Output, Input, EventEmitter, HostListener, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy,
            SimpleChanges, OnChanges
        } from '@angular/core';
        import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
        import { TimepickerEvent } from './timepicker-event-interface';
        declare var jQuery: any; 

    @Component({
        selector: 'datetime',
        template: `
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div id="{{idDatePicker}}" class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       [attr.readonly]="readonly"
                       [attr.placeholder]="datepickerOptions.placeholder || 'Choose date'"
                       [(ngModel)]="dateModel"
                       (keyup)="checkEmptyValue($event)"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span [ngClass]="datepickerOptions.icon || 'glyphicon glyphicon-th'"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="{{idTimePicker}}" type="text" class="form-control input-small" 
                       [attr.readonly]="readonly"
                       [attr.placeholder]="timepickerOptions.placeholder || 'Set time'"
                       [(ngModel)]="timeModel"
                       (keyup)="checkEmptyValue($event)">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i [ngClass]="timepickerOptions.icon || 'glyphicon glyphicon-time'"></i></span>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="hasClearButton" type="button" (click)="onClearClick()">Clear</button>
        </div>
       `
    })
    export class NKDatetime implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
        @Output()
        dateChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();

        @Input('timepicker')
        timepickerOptions: any = {};

        @Input('datepicker')
        datepickerOptions: any = {};

        @Input('hasClearButton')
        hasClearButton: boolean = false;

        @Input()
        readonly: boolean = null;

        date: Date; // ngModel
        dateModel: string;
        timeModel: string;

        // instances
        datepicker: any;
        timepicker: any;

        private idDatePicker: string = uniqueId('q-datepicker_');
        private idTimePicker: string = uniqueId('q-timepicker_');

        @HostListener('dateChange', ['$event'])
        onChange = (_: any) => {
        };
        onTouched = () => {
        };

        constructor(ngControl: NgControl) {
            ngControl.valueAccessor = this; // override valueAccessor
        }

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.init();
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
            if (this.datepicker) {
                this.datepicker.datepicker('destroy');
            }
            if (this.timepicker) {
                this.timepicker.timepicker('remove');
            }
        }

        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
            if (changes) {
                if (changes['datepickerOptions'] && this.datepicker) {
                    this.datepicker.datepicker('destroy');

                    if (changes['datepickerOptions'].currentValue) {
                        this.datepicker = null;
                        this.init();
                    } else if (changes['datepickerOptions'].currentValue === false) {
                        this.datepicker.remove();
                    }
                }
                if (changes['timepickerOptions'] && this.timepicker) {
                    this.timepicker.timepicker('remove');

                    if (changes['timepickerOptions'].currentValue) {
                        this.timepicker = null;
                        this.init();
                    } else if (changes['timepickerOptions'].currentValue === false) {
                        this.timepicker.parent().remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        writeValue(value: any): void {
            this.date = value;
            if (isDate(this.date)) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.updateModel(this.date);
                }, 0);
            }
        }

        registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
            this.onChange = fn;
        }

        registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
            this.onTouched = fn;
        }

        checkEmptyValue(e: any) {
            const value = e.target.value;
            if (value === '' && (
                    this.timepickerOptions === false ||
                    this.datepickerOptions === false ||
                    (this.timeModel === '' && this.dateModel === '')
                )) {
                this.dateChange.emit(null);
            }
        }

        onClearClick() {
            this.dateChange.emit(null);
            if (this.timepicker) {
                this.timepicker.timepicker('setTime', null);
            }
            this.updateDatepicker(null);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////

        private init(): void {
            if (!this.datepicker && this.datepickerOptions !== false) {
                let options = jQuery.extend({ enableOnReadonly: !this.readonly }, this.datepickerOptions);
                this.datepicker = (<any>jQuery('#' + this.idDatePicker)).datepicker(options);
                this.datepicker
                    .on('changeDate', (e: any) => {
                        let newDate: Date = e.date;

                        if (isDate(this.date) && isDate(newDate)) {
                            // get hours/minutes
                            var h = this.date.getHours();
                            var m = this.date.getMinutes();
                            newDate.setHours(h);
                            newDate.setMinutes(m);
                        }

                        this.date = newDate;
                        this.dateChange.emit(newDate);
                    });
            } else if (this.datepickerOptions === false) {
                (<any>jQuery('#' + this.idDatePicker)).remove();
            }

            if (!this.timepicker && this.timepickerOptions !== false) {
                let options = jQuery.extend({ defaultTime: false }, this.timepickerOptions);
                this.timepicker = (<any>jQuery('#' + this.idTimePicker)).timepicker(options);
                this.timepicker
                    .on('changeTime.timepicker', (e: TimepickerEvent) => {
                        let { meridian, hours } = e.time;

                        if (meridian) {
                            // has meridian -> convert 12 to 24h
                            if (meridian === 'PM' && hours < 12) {
                                hours = hours + 12;
                            }
                            if (meridian === 'AM' && hours === 12) {
                                hours = hours - 12;
                            }
                            hours = parseInt(this.pad(hours));
                        }

                        if (!isDate(this.date)) {
                            this.date = new Date();
                            this.updateDatepicker(this.date);
                        }

                        this.date.setHours(hours);
                        this.date.setMinutes(e.time.minutes);
                        this.dateChange.emit(this.date);
                    });
            } else if (this.timepickerOptions === false) {
                (<any>jQuery('#' + this.idTimePicker)).parent().remove();
            }
        }

        private updateModel(date: Date): void {
            this.updateDatepicker(date);

            // update timepicker
            if (this.timepicker !== undefined) {
                let hours = date.getHours();
                if (this.timepickerOptions.showMeridian) {
                    // Convert 24 to 12 hour system
                    hours = (hours === 0 || hours === 12) ? 12 : hours % 12;
                }
                const meridian = date.getHours() >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
                const time =
                    this.pad(hours) + ':' +
                    this.pad(this.date.getMinutes()) +
                    (this.timepickerOptions.showMeridian || this.timepickerOptions.showMeridian === undefined
                        ? meridian : '');
                this.timepicker.timepicker('setTime', time);
                this.timeModel = time; // fix initial empty timeModel bug
            }
        }

        private updateDatepicker(value?: any) {
            if (this.datepicker !== undefined) {
                this.datepicker.datepicker('update', value);
            }
        }

        private pad(value: any): string {
            return value.toString().length < 2 ? '0' + value : value.toString();
        }
    }

    let id: number = 0;
    function uniqueId(prefix: string): string {
        return prefix + ++id;
    }

    function isDate(obj: any) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Date]';
    }
```

> ```
> System.config.json
> ```

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      moment:'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',

      'mydatepicker' :'npm:mydatepicker',


      'ng2-datetime': "npm:ng2-datetime",
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      'ng2-datetime': {
                main: './ng2-datetime.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
      mydatepicker : {
        main :'./index.js',
        defaultExtension:'js'
      },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

> error console image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let import some libs

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css';
import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';
import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css';
import 'ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js';
```

I'm using angular-seed, so I will add the above libs in the project in the config file
Please read more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497253/trouble-getting-ng2-datetime-imported/42153734#42153734)

Answer (score 0):

just import these lines to index.html after

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

lines:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Angular2, the main idea is to not use jQuery where you can avoid it. If some dependency of yours uses it, you should still include it as a dependency in your module loader.

The typeerror is failing on 'datepicker' is not a function, but because ZoneJS/UMD is interfering with your error logging, it could be that either your "datepicker" dependency isn't loaded properly (or isn't made available properly through the Angular2 module loader), or your jQuery variable (`$`) is not available.

Comment: Sir what should i do ?  i really want to use bootstrap datepicker ng2-datetime.

Comment: You are using this package: https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/  ?

Comment: Yes, i am using with this package.